# Using Large Integer and decimal data types in SAP HANA

Tags: database, types, storage, biginteger, hana

I came across the following article https://blogs.saphana.com/2013/04/07/best-practices-for-sap-hana-data-loads/ and was wondering why it is a good practice not to use large integer and decimal types as data types for columns in HANA, the reason being they cannot use SIMD instructions optimally. I am not able to link SIMD instructions with large integer / decimal data types. Could somebody please illustrate why it is so ..TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you refer to this part of the blog post:

> [...] Same with large integer and decimal fields – they are more expensive because they can’t use such efficient SIMD instructions. [...]

This statement is inaccurate and you can safely ignore it.